# Parse full email address included name

Tags: go

I need get domain from email address, problem is same email have name included `name < email >`, 
my curent code is :

```
var (
    ErrBadFormat        = errors.New("invalid format")
    emailRegexp = regexp.MustCompile("^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$")
)

func GetFromDomain(email string) string {
    if !emailRegexp.MatchString(email) {
        fmt.Println("Error %FROMDOMAIN ", email)
        return "localhost"
    }

    i := strings.LastIndexByte(email, '@')
    return email[i+1:]
}
```

What is the best practice to do this? My method with LastIndexByte return error when email have name included. How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a proper email parsing library, such as the standard library's [`mail.ParseAddress`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/mail/#ParseAddress) method.

From there, you can easily extract the domain name from the address, by splitting on `@`--but be careful! It's actually legal to have a quoted or escaped `@` in the username portion of the email address (i.e. `"foo@bar"@example.com`), so you must split on the *last* `@`.

Comment: It's also fine to have no `@` in the e-mail address at all.

Comment: I'd also note that `net/mail` does not support some (really weird) e-mail address format dating back to RFC 822 but it should be fine on most of the real-world addresses.